# Oracle error 12154 while importing DMP file

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, import

#### My Setup

I'm running *Windows 7* 64-bit, using Oracle DB 11g R2 for Windows 64-bit. I have Oracle SQL Developer Release 3.0 (4.0.2.15.21) as the GUI for my database.

---

#### Question

I followed the instructions from [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23390/import-a-oracle-dmp-file-into-a-fresh-install-of-oracle) on how to import an Oracle .DMP file. I issued this command into the command prompt: `C:\>imp sys@dev/password12345 FROMUSER=FOOADMIN TOUSER=FOOADMIN file=c:\fooadmin.dmp full=yes`

It then prompts me for a password in which I enter the correct one and then I receive this error:

```
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 12154 encountered
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

**Actual Question:** How do I fix this error and be able to import the .dmp file successfully? Or what are some steps I can head towards to potentially get this working...?

---

#### My Files & What I've Done

I have looked through countless posts on this same issue. My **tnsnames.ora**, **listener.ora**, & **sqlnet.ora** are located in this directory: `C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome\NETWORK\ADMIN`

My connection in my **tnsnames.ora** file looks like this (I have also tried to put my computer name as the HOST, instead of 127.0.0.1)...

```
DEV =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = DEV)
  )
 )
```

---

#### PATH Variables

I added the following to my PATH (I realize there may be some unnecessary item in there, I just wanted to be on the safe side. ):
`C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome\bin;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;`

I also created two more variables in my System Variables...

**`TNS_ADMIN`** `C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome\NETWORK\ADMIN`

**`TNS_NAMES`** `C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome\NETWORK\ADMIN`

Comment: sys@dev/password12345 is not a proper specification. sys/password12345@dev is the right one. Don't use sys for export and import.

Comment: @miracle173 Using `sys/password12345@dev`, I got this error `connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPERUsername: SYSDBA` ... but are you saying that using **sys** in general will not work?

Comment: The following work for me from windows command prompt: `imp userid=<user-name>/<password>@<oracle-server-name>:<port>/<service-name> file=<file-name-with-path.dmp> FULL=Y` Port: Usually 1521
Service Name: Usually ORCL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this on Windows (three nested double quotes):

```
exp system/password_for_system@dev file=c:\fooadmin.dmp full=yes

imp """sys/password12345@dev as sysdba""" FROMUSER=FOOADMIN TOUSER=FOOADMIN file=c:\fooadmin.dmp
```

In general imp would work as intended with sys account, it is just not recommended. But exp with sys account could possibly produce inconsistent dump file silently. So it's better to avoid it, for example use `system`.

Comment: I had to get rid of the `full=yes`, but other than that it worked! It would give me this error when I had `full=yes` ... `IMP-00024: Only one mode (TABLES, FROMUSER, or FULL) can be specified`

Comment: True, I haven't noticed it :) Edited my answer for the sake of future readers.