# How do I import data into oracle 11g r2 using a `.dmp` file and a `.par` file?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, datapump

How do I import data into a new installation of oracle 11g r2 using a `.dmp` file and a `.par` file?

Here is what I have done so far, on a Windows 8.1 devbox:

```
1.) Open command line as administrator
2.) C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqlplus / as sysdba
This will reveal the SQL prompt as follows:  
    SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Feb 25 14:20:46 2016
    Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
    Connected to:
    Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
    With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
    SQL> CREATE DIRECTORY DMPDIR AS 'C:\path\to\DumpDir\';
    SQL> exit;
3.) Then back in windows command prompt:  
C:\WINDOWS\system32>impdp parfile=C:\path\to\DumpDir\impdp.par;
```

Then I read [this other posting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/how-to-transfer-data-using-expdp-and-impdp-commands) which contains the following answer code:

```
impdp user/pass schemas=schema1 directory=dumpdir \
  remap_schema=schema1:schema2 \
  dumpfile=schema1.dmp \
  logfile=impdp_schema2.log
```

Since my question is slightly different, I guessed at the following, which I have not typed yet:

```
impdp schemas=schema1 directory=dumpdir \
  dumpfile=schema1.dmp \
  logfile=impdp_logfile.log
```

What is the correct syntax to use?  And what other steps should I take to do this properly?

Comment: Do you need Syntax to use data pump import? Syntax may vary version to version so why not to see Oracle Docs? [Data Pump Import](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_import.htm)

Comment: @JSapkota I was not using `Syntax` as a key word or name, I was using syntax meaning what specific characters do I type.  Yes, I found your link before posting this question, but its contents are not clear to me.  I am used to MySQL, which has very clear and easy documentation that lists specific sequences of commands.  Can you suggest what commands to type?

Comment: Well in that case what you are importing tablespace or schema or single table? so it depends upon your logical objects that you to import

Comment: @JSapkota I am importing many tables containing lots of data.

Comment: @JSapkota I found the `impdp` command from the windows command line, but it asks for a username and password.  The oracle installation just has an administration password with no other users set up yet.  I know the administration password, but I don't know how to use it to accomplish what I am seeking to accomplish, or how to narrow the question to produce usable steps.

Answer (score 3):

The PAR file is a parameter file, which contains parameters for data pump that you don't need to enter on the command line.  Without knowing what those are, we can't advise what you need to use in any detail.

Generally speaking, if you have a parameter file, you just put that on the command line:

```
impdp user/pass parfile=/path/to/parfile
```

However, there may be other parameters required.

Assuming you have a parameter file, you need the command line to contain at minimum:

```
Username
Parfile
```

To perform an import, you need at minimum these parameters defined between the command line and parameter file:

```
Username
Directory
Dumpfile
Full OR Schemas OR Tables
(and for good practice, Logfile)
```

For a basic import, those four parameters between the command line and the parameter file will import data.  Without knowing what you're trying to achieve, anything else is guesswork.